# Query optimization. Duplicate subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

We found a slow query in our legacy system. What I see in the query is a duplicate fragment. Here's the full query:

```
DECLARE @SellerId INT;
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME;
DECLARE @DateTo DATETIME;

SET @SellerId = 5396884;
SET @DateFrom = '2016-01-05';
SET @DateTo = '2016-10-08';

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME;
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE();



CREATE TABLE #ReportDate (codes INT, dates DATETIME);
DECLARE @dif as INT;
DECLARE @cont as INT;
DECLARE @currdate as DATETIME;
SET @dif = DATEDIFF(day, @DateFrom, @DateTo);
SET @cont = 1;
SET @currdate = @DateFrom - 1;
WHILE (@cont <= @dif + 1)
BEGIN
    SET @currdate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @currdate);
    INSERT INTO #ReportDate VALUES (@cont, @currdate);
    SET @cont = @cont + 1;
END


/* HOW TO OPTIMIZE THIS ONE? */
SELECT
        #ReportDate.dates as valid_date,
        (
          SELECT 

          COUNT(DISTINCT(nonCancelledSales.num_remito)) as actives

          FROM      
                (

                    SELECT *

                    FROM salesView

                    WHERE

                        salesView.sell_id NOT IN 
                            (
                              SELECT sell_id

                              FROM salesStates

                              WHERE
                                  salesStates.aborted = 1
                            ) 

                  ) nonCancelledSales

          WHERE
                nonCancelledSales.seller_id = @SellerId AND
                nonCancelledSales.cancelled = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.void = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.hasDiscount = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.dateOfSale <=  #ReportDate.dates AND
                nonCancelledSales.currentState =  (SELECT   MAX(hveest.date)

                                              FROM  salesStates hveest

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hveest.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hveest.date <= #ReportDate.dates) AND
                nonCancelledSales.lastProductDate = (SELECT     MAX(hvepro.date)

                                              FROM  productHistory hvepro

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hvepro.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hvepro.date <= #ReportDate.dates) 

        ) total_actives,

        (
          SELECT 

          ISNULL(SUM(nonCancelledSales.paymentValue),0) as active

          FROM      
                (

                    SELECT *

                    FROM salesView

                    WHERE

                        salesView.sell_id NOT IN 
                            (
                              SELECT sell_id

                              FROM salesStates

                              WHERE
                                  salesStates.aborted = 1
                            ) 

                  ) nonCancelledSales

          WHERE
                nonCancelledSales.seller_id = @SellerId AND
                nonCancelledSales.cancelled = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.void = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.hasDiscount = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.dateOfSale <=  #ReportDate.dates AND
                nonCancelledSales.currentState =  (SELECT   MAX(hveest.date)

                                              FROM  salesStates hveest

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hveest.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hveest.date <= #ReportDate.dates) AND
                nonCancelledSales.lastProductDate = (SELECT     MAX(hvepro.date)

                                              FROM  productHistory hvepro

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hvepro.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hvepro.date <= #ReportDate.dates)             
        ) active
FROM 
        #ReportDate
GROUP BY
        #ReportDate.dates



DROP TABLE #ReportDate
```

Here are the two duplicated fragments I see:

```
(
          SELECT 

          COUNT(DISTINCT(nonCancelledSales.num_remito)) as actives

          FROM      
                (

                    SELECT *

                    FROM salesView

                    WHERE

                        salesView.sell_id NOT IN 
                            (
                              SELECT sell_id

                              FROM salesStates

                              WHERE
                                  salesStates.aborted = 1
                            ) 

                  ) nonCancelledSales

          WHERE
                nonCancelledSales.seller_id = @SellerId AND
                nonCancelledSales.cancelled = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.void = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.hasDiscount = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.dateOfSale <=  #ReportDate.dates AND
                nonCancelledSales.currentState =  (SELECT   MAX(hveest.date)

                                              FROM  salesStates hveest

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hveest.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hveest.date <= #ReportDate.dates) AND
                nonCancelledSales.lastProductDate = (SELECT     MAX(hvepro.date)

                                              FROM  productHistory hvepro

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hvepro.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hvepro.date <= #ReportDate.dates) 

        ) total_actives,

        (
          SELECT 

          ISNULL(SUM(nonCancelledSales.paymentValue),0) as active

          FROM      
                (

                    SELECT *

                    FROM salesView

                    WHERE

                        salesView.sell_id NOT IN 
                            (
                              SELECT sell_id

                              FROM salesStates

                              WHERE
                                  salesStates.aborted = 1
                            ) 

                  ) nonCancelledSales

          WHERE
                nonCancelledSales.seller_id = @SellerId AND
                nonCancelledSales.cancelled = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.void = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.hasDiscount = 0 AND
                nonCancelledSales.dateOfSale <=  #ReportDate.dates AND
                nonCancelledSales.currentState =  (SELECT   MAX(hveest.date)

                                              FROM  salesStates hveest

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hveest.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hveest.date <= #ReportDate.dates) AND
                nonCancelledSales.lastProductDate = (SELECT     MAX(hvepro.date)

                                              FROM  productHistory hvepro

                                              WHERE 
                                                    hvepro.sell_id = nonCancelledSales.sell_id AND
                                                    hvepro.date <= #ReportDate.dates)             
        ) active
```

Is it fully necessary to duplicate the query ? In the first one he's getting:

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT(nonCancelledSales.num_remito)) as actives
```

on the second one:

```
  ISNULL(SUM(nonCancelledSales.paymentValue),0) as active
```

I suppose there has to be some way to rewrite the query but I'm not sure how.

Comment: looks like it was all one query at one time, which would explain the `GROUP BY #ReportDate.dates`

Comment: You could also speed this up by dropping that loop and using a tally table instead to populate your list of dates. This is not likely the worst part performance wise but it is super easy to make this set based instead of a loop. Here is a great article explaining tally tables and how they can replace loops. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @JamieD77 are you saying the group by is superfluous?

Comment: Don't you have a way to JOIN the tables? It looks like you do. Just as an example, the select you are doing to the salesStates table is happening for each and every one of the results in the query to the salesView table. It is usually a bad idea to do queries like that directly to the columns.

Comment: @JuanCarlosEduardoRomainaAc, what do you mean by JOIN the tables? you mean create a new table?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson I mean use identity columns and use the JOIN clause, For example, seems like salesView and salesStates have the sell_id column, so you can JOIN by that. If you add the table definitions, I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these, if you use `OUTER APPLY`.

The idea is:

```
SELECT . . ., x.actives, x.active
FROM #ReportDate OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(nonCancelledSales.num_remito)) as actives, 
             COALESCE(SUM(nonCancelledSales.paymentValue), 0) as active
      . . . -- rest of query here
     ) x;
```

In this case, `OUTER APPLY` is a lot like a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause that can return multiple rows.

Comment: So using OUTER APPLY is the only and best way to rewrite this query? I thought outer apply was for table valued functions instead

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson . . . It is the most obvious way to write the logic.  A subquery can only return one value, so it gets around that problem.  I don't understand the logic, so there may be some way to write it more simply.  But `APPLY` implements what is called a "lateral join".  Table valued functions are just one application.